# redirect to not current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a trobble with redirect in rails 4.
I need to redirect to a page specified in a specific situation. Back redirect does not work , because the page I need to redirect is not the previous page, and I just need to redirect to this page when the user clicks on a link.
The code:
View where user click:

```
<li >
  <%= link_to new_admin_wine_path do %>
    <span>
      Cadastrar um novo vinho
    </span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Page to where I need redirect when I click in that link:
new_admin_wine_path

controller:

```
def store_location
    return unless request.get?
    if (request.path != new_user_session_path &&
        request.path != new_user_registration_path &&
        request.path != new_user_password_path &&
        request.path != edit_user_password_path &&
        request.path != "/:locale/users/confirmation(" &&
        request.path != destroy_user_session_path &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
    end
  end
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path    
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). Basically, you're going to want to structure your controller:

```
class someController < ActionController::Base
    after_filter :redirect_method, only: [:whatever, :actions, :you, :want]
    def store_location
        return unless request.get?
        if (request.path != new_user_session_path &&
            request.path != new_user_registration_path &&
            request.path != new_user_password_path &&
            request.path != edit_user_password_path &&
            request.path != "/:locale/users/confirmation(" &&
            request.path != destroy_user_session_path &&
            !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
          session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
        end
      end
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        session[:previous_url] || root_path    
      end
     def redirect_method
        redirect_to root_path (or whevever you want to send them) 
     end
end
```